# Looping through arrays with JavaScript on Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have some javascript here that basically loops through certain values on my page and adds a class depending on the value. This works perfectly on chrome and safari but on firefox it doesn't seem to work as it should. Im guessing there is a different way to write it for firefox to render it properly but can't seem to pin point the problem. I know this is something jQuery can handle for you but i want to just use javascript.

```
function ranks() {

 var scores = document.querySelectorAll('.MyScore'); // get all elements with .MyScore

 Array.prototype.forEach.call(scores, function (item) { // iterate the elements

    var score = parseInt(item.innerText, 10); // get the value from the text and parse it

    if (score > 80) {
        item.classList.add('great'); // add great to the item classList


    } else if (score > 60 && score < 80) {
        item.classList.add('okay'); // add okey to the item classList

    } else if(score == 0) {
        item.classList.add('no-score'); // add bad to the item classList

    } else {
        item.classList.add('bad'); // add bad to the item classList

    }
});


}
ranks();
```

You can compare this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wupehaxagu/edit?html,css,js,output) on different browsers to see what i mean.

Comment: Try to use a `for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)` loop instead.

Comment: `.innerText` do not exists in FF, use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: yes, thank you. Tried searching that before hand but didn't know how to search for something like that.